# PySpark foreachPartition write to Database in Parallel

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm reading in hundreds of XML files into a Spark Dataframe, where each row consist of meta data and time series data for a particular event. Each one of these rows is converted into a rdd to be transformed into batches of documents with a particular key/vale structure and then written over to a database. The XML data need to be broken into batches <50Kb, hence the helper function to produce then batches shown below.

```
def build_documents(data):

    # Make dataframe out of data tags
    data = pd.DataFrame([i.split(',') for i in list(chain(*(data)))])

    # Helper function to Get Batches
    for batch in get_batches(data): 
          x = batch.T.to_dict()
          yield x

def process_partition(partition):
   client = document_client.DocumentClient(HOST, {'masterKey': MASTER_KEY} )
   for element in partition:
        generator = build_documents(element)
        for batch in generator:
            client.CreateDocument(collection_link + 'data', batch)


# Write to Database
df.rdd.coalesce(20).foreachPartition(process_partition)
```

Still tuning the number of partitions, but any thoughts on how this can be improved? Performance is really slow, as expected with the code implemented so far. The cluster consist of 32 cores, 128.0 GB Memory for both driver and can scale up to 8 executors. As shown below, there is only two workers running, which obviously is not optimal when scaling up further. Thoughts?

[image]

[image]

Comment: While you seem to have some problems with data distribution it looks more like a problem with your Python code and / or service you use. 21 minutes for 73 records  / 38MB looks just unrealistically long. Unless you provide more details it might be hard to help you.

Answer (score -1):

`df.rdd.coalesce(20).foreachPartition(process_partition)` will write sequential entries to database. and morever your logic for function process_partition will also be sequential.

You need to multithread the logic for def `process_partition`. That will speed up the process. Also use `df.rdd.coalesce(20).foreachPartitionAsync(process_partition)`

Comment: This is incorrect in more than one way. 1. foreachPartition can run different partitions on different workers at the same time. 2. you should try and batch the rows in the partition to a bulk write, to save time, creating one connection to the DB per partition and closing it at the end of the partition.